# iPhone app crashing on iOS 17 with shared_tcpConnWorkQueue

Tags: ios, crashlytics

My app was working fine before iOS 17 for all users. I am on iOS 17.0 though, but my app is not crashing. From the firebase crashlytics I am seeing hundreds of crashes because of `shared_tcpConnWorkQueue`.

Looks like the app is not even opening, it's an early crash as reported by Crashlytics (<1 second from app open).

What could be the possible way to fix this? I am attaching stacktrace of the crash:

```
# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Application: com.mymyapp.ios
# Platform: apple
# Version: 3.1.4 (124)
# Issue: 21084b00947d6d3eccc189c81a313bc5
# Session: 5d591998851244ef940b35a0425eb554_DNE_0_v2
# Date: Thu Sep 28 2023 09:25:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreAutoLayout                 0x48d4 expression_shrink_if_possible + 144
1  CoreAutoLayout                 0x4144 NSISLinExpAddVar + 304
2  UIKitCore                      0x2d568 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:onBehalfOfLayoutGuide:] + 2280
3  UIKitCore                      0x2cc68 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 236
4  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1fe8 -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 72
5  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1eec -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 124
6  UIKitCore                      0x4dcf8 -[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 492
7  UIKitCore                      0x4dad8 -[UIView _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 168
8  UIKitCore                      0x4d9b8 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_addConstraint:] + 76
9  CoreAutoLayout                 0xa898 __55+[NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:]_block_invoke + 40
10 CoreAutoLayout                 0xa5f8 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 84
11 CoreAutoLayout                 0xa348 +[NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:] + 308
12 myapp                           0x72315c BottomBar.setup() + 120 (BottomBar.swift:120)
13 myapp                           0x722bd8 BottomBar.onTabChange(isLean:) + 66 (BottomBar.swift:66)
14 myapp                           0x725f94 partial apply for closure #1 in BottomBar.setup() + 82 (BottomBar.swift:82)
15 myapp                           0x70eb28 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Notification?) -> () + 4386220840 (<compiler-generated>:4386220840)
16 myapp                           0x70ebbc thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable (@in_guaranteed Notification) -> () + 4386220988 (<compiler-generated>:4386220988)
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2fc64 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 128
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2f640 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2f588 _CFXRegistrationPost + 440
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2ead8 _CFXNotificationPost + 724
21 Foundation                     0x2b7e4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
22 myapp                           0x70e484 closure #1 in static SwiftEventBus.postToMainThread(_:sender:) + 4386219140
23 myapp                           0x3e6f8 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4379076344 (<compiler-generated>:4379076344)
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x12998 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 984
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x125b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
28 CoreFoundation                 0x379bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
29 CoreFoundation                 0x346c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
30 CoreFoundation                 0x33e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
31 GraphicsServices               0x35ec GSEventRunModal + 164
32 UIKitCore                      0x22f350 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
33 UIKitCore                      0x22e98c UIApplicationMain + 340
34 myapp                           0x8e3eec main + 35 (AppDelegate.swift:35)
35 ???                            0x1b2303d44 (Missing)

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.binary-images
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1cb0 write + 8
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x15514 FIRCLSSDKFileLog + 316
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x73c8 __FIRCLSBinaryImageChanged_block_invoke + 412
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0xb894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
6  libdispatch.dylib              0xc3c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x17004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x16878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x116c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x4918 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 64
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x4f14 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x15080 -[FIRCLSInstallIdentifierModel regenerateInstallIDIfNeeded] + 200
4  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x20b54 __91-[FIRCLSReportUploader prepareAndSubmitReport:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:withProcessing:]_block_invoke_2 + 36
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x5b3c _dispatch_once_callout + 32
7  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x20b2c __91-[FIRCLSReportUploader prepareAndSubmitReport:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:withProcessing:]_block_invoke + 904
8  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x5ddc FIRCLSApplicationActivity + 72
9  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x2075c -[FIRCLSReportUploader prepareAndSubmitReport:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:withProcessing:] + 172
10 FirebaseCrashlytics            0x109b8 __92-[FIRCLSExistingReportManager processExistingActiveReportPath:dataCollectionToken:asUrgent:]_block_invoke_2 + 52
11 Foundation                     0x49c00 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
12 Foundation                     0x7b0ec -[NSBlockOperation main] + 104
13 Foundation                     0x78974 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 16
14 Foundation                     0x77a64 -[NSOperation start] + 648
15 Foundation                     0x7a57c __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 16
16 Foundation                     0x7a2e8 __NSOQSchedule_f + 172
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x13250 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 148
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
19 libdispatch.dylib              0xb894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
20 libdispatch.dylib              0xc3c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x17004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x16878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19fc start_wqthread + 438

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x11d8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xf70 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xe88 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xcc8 mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x364bc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x343b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x33e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7  Foundation                     0x2d4cc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8  Foundation                     0x5c234 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9  UIKitCore                      0x19120c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420
10 Foundation                     0xb3154 __NSThread__start__ + 732
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24d4 _pthread_start + 136
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a10 thread_start + 8

GCDAsyncSocket-CFStreamThreadSetup
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b7c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xfd4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2  Foundation                     0x7518c8 -[_NSThreadPerformInfo wait] + 44
3  Foundation                     0xfde84 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 720
4  Foundation                     0x1262a0 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 108
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x136b4 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  CocoaAsyncSocket               0x12ef4 -[GCDAsyncSocket addStreamsToRunLoop] + 100
8  CocoaAsyncSocket               0xb150 __29-[GCDAsyncSocket didConnect:]_block_invoke_2 + 40
9  CocoaAsyncSocket               0xb27c __29-[GCDAsyncSocket didConnect:]_block_invoke_4 + 36
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
12 libdispatch.dylib              0xb894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
13 libdispatch.dylib              0xc3c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x17004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x16878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19fc start_wqthread + 438

com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1d08 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d68 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 84
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x17f0 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 248
3  libsystem_info.dylib           0x106ac _mdns_search_ex + 2544
4  libsystem_info.dylib           0xf644 mdns_addrinfo + 360
5  libsystem_info.dylib           0x123e4 search_addrinfo + 176
6  libsystem_info.dylib           0x76d0 si_addrinfo + 1312
7  libsystem_info.dylib           0x7108 getaddrinfo + 168
8  CocoaAsyncSocket               0x16b30 __63-[GCDAsyncUdpSocket asyncResolveHost:port:withCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke.72 + 428
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x744c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 928
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x15be4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x163ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1928 _pthread_wqthread + 228
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1d08 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d68 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 84
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x17f0 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 248
3  libsystem_info.dylib           0xfef4 _mdns_search_ex + 568
4  libsystem_info.dylib           0xf644 mdns_addrinfo + 360
5  libsystem_info.dylib           0x123e4 search_addrinfo + 176
6  libsystem_info.dylib           0x76d0 si_addrinfo + 1312
7  libsystem_info.dylib           0x7108 getaddrinfo + 168
8  CocoaAsyncSocket               0x16b30 __63-[GCDAsyncUdpSocket asyncResolveHost:port:withCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke.72 + 428
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x744c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 928
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x15be4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x163ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1928 _pthread_wqthread + 228
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1c3e0 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 184
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1c7c0 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1176
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x147f0 FIRCLSHandler + 48
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x17184 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 1248
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24d4 _pthread_start + 136
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a10 thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9730 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19b0 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Crashed: shared_tcpConnWorkQueue
0  ???                            0x206daf374 (Missing)
1  ???                            0x206dae1b8 (Missing)
2  CFNetwork                      0x118b84 _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 244188
3  CFNetwork                      0x11757c _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 238548
4  CFNetwork                      0x11a76c _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 251332
5  CFNetwork                      0x11d590 _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 263144
6  CFNetwork                      0x11c07c _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 257748
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
9  libdispatch.dylib              0xb894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
10 libdispatch.dylib              0xc3c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x17004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x16878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xd8c0 __select + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xd8c0 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 8
2  CoreFoundation                 0xe06e4 __CFSocketManager + 636
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24d4 _pthread_start + 136
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a10 thread_start + 8

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x11d8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xf70 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xe88 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xcc8 mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x364bc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x343b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x33e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7  CFNetwork                      0x258798 _CFURLStorageSessionCopyIdentifier + 69132
8  Foundation                     0xb3154 __NSThread__start__ + 732
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24d4 _pthread_start + 136
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a10 thread_start + 8

GCDAsyncSocket-CFStream
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1d08 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d68 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 84
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x17f0 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 248
3  CFNetwork                      0x1146b4 _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 226572
4  CoreFoundation                 0xda3a0 _CFStreamScheduleWithRunLoop + 1508
5  CocoaAsyncSocket               0x12a00 +[GCDAsyncSocket scheduleCFStreams:] + 64
6  Foundation                     0xf6064 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 264
7  CoreFoundation                 0x37acc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
8  CoreFoundation                 0x36d48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
9  CoreFoundation                 0x354fc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
10 CoreFoundation                 0x34238 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
11 CoreFoundation                 0x33e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
12 Foundation                     0x2d4cc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
13 CocoaAsyncSocket               0x12970 +[GCDAsyncSocket cfstreamThread:] + 276
14 Foundation                     0xb3154 __NSThread__start__ + 732
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24d4 _pthread_start + 136
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a10 thread_start + 8

com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xd8ec __select_nocancel + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xd8ec select$DARWIN_EXTSN$NOCANCEL + 8
2  libsystem_dnssd.dylib          0x1570 deliver_request + 692
3  libsystem_dnssd.dylib          0x3234 DNSServiceQueryRecordInternal + 716
4  libsystem_info.dylib           0x10b8c _mdns_query_start + 624
5  libsystem_info.dylib           0xffa8 _mdns_search_ex + 748
6  libsystem_info.dylib           0xf644 mdns_addrinfo + 360
7  libsystem_info.dylib           0x123e4 search_addrinfo + 176
8  libsystem_info.dylib           0x76d0 si_addrinfo + 1312
9  libsystem_info.dylib           0x7108 getaddrinfo + 168
10 CocoaAsyncSocket               0x16b30 __63-[GCDAsyncUdpSocket asyncResolveHost:port:withCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke.72 + 428
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x744c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 928
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x15be4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x163ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1928 _pthread_wqthread + 228
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9730 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19b0 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19fc start_wqthread + 438

com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1d08 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d68 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 84
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x17f0 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 248
3  libsystem_info.dylib           0xfef4 _mdns_search_ex + 568
4  libsystem_info.dylib           0xf644 mdns_addrinfo + 360
5  libsystem_info.dylib           0x123e4 search_addrinfo + 176
6  libsystem_info.dylib           0x76d0 si_addrinfo + 1312
7  libsystem_info.dylib           0x7108 getaddrinfo + 168
8  CocoaAsyncSocket               0x16b30 __63-[GCDAsyncUdpSocket asyncResolveHost:port:withCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke.72 + 428
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x744c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 928
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x15be4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x163ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1928 _pthread_wqthread + 228
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9730 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19b0 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

cocoa.lumberjack
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1c2c kevent_id + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x26b10 _dispatch_kq_poll + 228
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x260ac _dispatch_event_loop_poke + 340
3  CocoaLumberjack                0xf194 -[DDLog lt_log:] + 288
4  CocoaLumberjack                0xdc54 __40-[DDLog queueLogMessage:asynchronously:]_block_invoke + 32
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7  libdispatch.dylib              0xb894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
8  libdispatch.dylib              0xc3c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x17004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x16878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1964 _pthread_wqthread + 288
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9730 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19b0 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9730 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19b0 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread + 8
```